# Running Keras Sequential model with different optimizers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

> I want to check the performance of my model against various optimizers
>   (sgd, rmsprop, adam, adamax etc)
>
> So i define a keras sequential model and then i do this

```
epochs = 50
print('--sgd start---')

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer_sgd = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='my_model_sgd.h5', 
                               verbose=1, save_best_only=True)


history_sgd = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          validation_split=0.2,epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, callbacks=[checkpointer_sgd],verbose=1)

print('--sgd end---')

print('--------------------------------------------')

print('--rmsprop start---')

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer_rmsprop = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='my_model_rmsprop.h5', 
                               verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history_rmsprop = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          validation_split=0.2,
          epochs=epochs, batch_size=32, callbacks=[checkpointer_rmsprop],verbose=1)

print('--rmsprop end---')
```

I do this for all the optimizers (in the code above have mentioned only sgd and rmsprop) and then execute the statements. So now what happens is the first optimizer starts from low accuracy and then accuracy is increased as more epochs happen. But the next optimizer starts from already a high accuracy.

> Is the above code correct or do i need to reset the model everytime
>   before i compile

See below the first epoch output for different optimizers

```
--sgd start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 46s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0510 - acc: 0.2985 - val_loss: 0.0442 - val_acc: 0.6986

--rmsprop start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 46s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0341 - acc: 0.5940 - val_loss: 0.0148 - val_acc: 0.6963

--adagrad start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 44s 26ms/step - loss: 0.0068 - acc: 0.6951 - val_loss: 0.0046 - val_acc: 0.6963

--adadelta start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 52s 30ms/step - loss: 8.0430e-04 - acc: 0.8125 - val_loss: 9.4660e-04 - val_acc: 0.7850

--adam start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 47s 27ms/step - loss: 7.7599e-04 - acc: 0.8201 - val_loss: 9.8981e-04 - val_acc: 0.7757

--adamax start---
Train on 1712 samples, validate on 428 samples
Epoch 1/50
1712/1712 [==============================] - 54s 31ms/step - loss: 6.4941e-04 - acc: 0.8359 - val_loss: 9.2495e-04 - val_acc: 0.7991
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use K.clear_session() which will clean up everything.

```
from keras import backend as K

def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    return model

model = get_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
K.clear_session() # it will destroy keras object

model1 = get_model()
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
K.clear_session()
```

This solution should solve your problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i didn't understand...what is K ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Use  K.clear_session() after fitting model to reset keras object.

Comment: @Nitin K is a reference to the backend engine Keras is running on. For example, K.placeholder(shape = (2,3,4)) is equivalent to tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (2,3,4)), if you're using the TensorFlow backend.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling the model does not change it's state. Weights learn before compilation will be same after compilation. You need to delete the model object to clear the weights and create a new one before compiling again.